# Refresh token doesn't fail after deleting the user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'd like to know if it's my failure or the bug/feature of ASP.NET Identity.

We use ASP.NET Identity 1.0 in our ASP.NET MVC 5 project. OAuth is configured like this:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "self";

        UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider()
            {
                OnCreate = CreateRefreshToken,
                OnReceive = ReceiveRefreshToken
            },
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static Func<SphUserManager> UserManagerFactory { get; set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login")
        });

        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }

    private static void CreateRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
    }
    private static void ReceiveRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
    }
}
```

We use Web API to register and login the user. Refresh token is than used to refresh access token. This is what we didn't expect:

1. Register the user
2. Login the user and obtain access token and refresh token (/token, grant_type=password...)
3. **Delete** the user (directly from database or in administration).
4. Call refresh token and the request will not fail. The access token is prolonged and the user is still authenticated (/token, grant_type=refresh_token...)

Is it correct behavior? Should I do something special to "invalidate" tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh token supports in the Katana OAuth2 middleware is essentially up to you, so if you delete the user then it's up to that logic to also revoke (delete) all refresh tokens for that user.

Comment: I would revoke the refresh token, but it is on the client. The user can be deleted from the web application (administration) and there's no connection with tokens.

Comment: Again, how you implement refresh tokens is up to you -- if you want the refresh token to be invalid when the user is deleted then you need to make this association.

Comment: I understand. I was hoping it would be easier. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I wish it were easier as well. See this for more perspective: http://leastprivilege.com/2014/03/24/the-web-api-v2-oauth2-authorization-server-middlewareis-it-worth-it/